# Excel list of distinct values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a table with a customer email in column A, and the product they bought in column B - there's around 60k rows.

**Data**

```
------------------------------------------------------
Email              |  Product  |        Time         | 
------------------------------------------------------
nayena@gmail.com   |     P1    | 27/02/2020 18:09:41 |
yenaye@hotmail.com |     P2    | 28/02/2020 17:09:32 |
nayena@gmail.com   |     P1    | 29/02/2020 14:05:46 |
yenaye@hotmail.com |     P1    | 29/02/2020 13:02:04 |
yenaye@hotmail.com |     P2    | 29/02/2020 20:05:21 |
```

I'm trying to make two new columns

One should be how many distinct products the customer has sold for.
The other should be a list of those distinct products. (Preferably ordered by date, which would be in another column) Desired result:

**Desired Result**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Email              |  Product  |        Time         |  Orders |  n  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
nayena@gmail.com   |     P1    | 27/02/2020 18:09:41 |  P1     |  1
yenaye@hotmail.com |     P2    | 28/02/2020 17:09:32 |  P1|P2  |  2
nayena@gmail.com   |     P1    | 29/02/2020 14:05:46 |  P1     |  1
yenaye@hotmail.com |     P1    | 29/02/2020 13:02:04 |  P1|P2  |  2
yenaye@hotmail.com |     P2    | 29/02/2020 20:05:21 |  P1|P2  |  2
```

I've tried something like

```
=FILTER(B:B,A:A=A2)
```

but its dropping down the values, spilling into cells below. And it doesn't do unique values.
This is a fairly standard operation in Python but I'd like to know how one does this in excel in the simplest way possible - it should be fairly straight forward I imagine.

I've tried something like

```
=AGGREGATE(3,0,FILTER(B:B,A:A=A2))
```

but I'm not clear on how `FILTER` is passed to `AGGREGATE`

Comment: You'll have to look into `UNIQUE()` and if you want to order look into `SORTYBY()`. If you have a small markdown sample data table we can help you out in more detail.

Comment: ah right - doing `UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=A2))` works but not when there's more than one, I get `#SPILL!` - Ideally I'd like it to be something like `Product 1|Product 2`. I'll try add markdown now

Comment: added some markdown - hope that is clear!

Answer (score 0):

Can't quite get what you show for your desired output, if you want the orders sorted by date.

One of your customers has `P2` as both the earliest and latest, so no matter which way you sort, it will come out `P2|P1`

The `Orders` formula below sorts by Date. (No need for sorting in the `n` formula)

```
Orders:  =TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER(SORT($A$2:$C$6,3,1 ),A2 = INDEX(SORT($A$2:$C$6,3,1 ),0,1)),0,2)))
n:       =COUNTA(UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$C$6,A2=$A$2:$A$6),0,2)))
```

[image]

To replicate your **Desired Result**, you'd have to sort by Product:

```
Orders:  =TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER(SORT($A$2:$C$6,2,1 ),A2 = INDEX(SORT($A$2:$C$6,2,1 ),0,1)),0,2)))
```

[image]

**Note:**

- *You can use whole column references, but it increases the calculation time significantly*
- *A Power Query solution is also easily doable, but depends on the specifics of exactly how you want the results presented*